# facebook android api send bitmap, message and link

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to send a text message, bitmap image (not url!) and a link to Facebook wall. I tried two ways:

The first is to use `me/feed`. It allows me to send message and link, but not image:

```
postParams.putByteArray("picture", data);
postParams.putString("message", "My message here");
postParams.putString("link", "http://www.google.com");

Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams, HttpMethod.POST, callback);
```

I receive an exception : "picture url is not properly formatted".

The second is to use `me/photos`:

```
postParams.putByteArray("photo", data);
postParams.putString("message", "My message here");
postParams.putString("link", "http://www.google.com");

Request request = new Request(session, "me/photos", postParams, HttpMethod.POST, callback);
```

In this case post is posted successfully and appears on the Facebook wall, but without the `link`.

How do I post these three things along?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is simple: one must unite message and link:

```
postParams.putByteArray("photo", data);
postParams.putString("message", "My message here http://www.google.com");
//postParams.putString("link", "http://www.google.com");

Request request = new Request(session, "me/photos", postParams, HttpMethod.POST, callback);
```